# Is there a way to use a button that was disabled, but then enabled

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import time

q1 = [
        [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(20,1), key="t")],
        [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?"), sg.Button("Start")],
        [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1",button_color=("#ffffff","#151515"), disabled=True, enable_events=True), sg.Button("Option 2", key="2",button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3",button_color=("#00ffff","#151515"), disabled=True), sg.Button("Option 4", key="4",button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip")]
    ]

window = sg.Window("Question 1",q1)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break
    if event == "Start":
        window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=False)
        window.Refresh()

        seconds = 6

        start = time()
        current = time()
        timeleft = seconds

        while timeleft > 0:
            window.FindElement("t").Update(timeleft)
            window.refresh()
            current = time()
            timeleft = int(seconds - (current - start))
            if timeleft == 0:
                sg.popup("no time left")

        if event == "1":
            sg.popup("Test 1")
        elif event == "2":
            sg.popup("Test 2")
        elif event == "3":
            sg.popup("Test 3")
        elif event == "4":
            sg.popup("Test 4")
```

This is the code I have tried to do it with. When start is clicked, a timer starts so the question to be answers, however, I dont want the buttons to be able to be clicked before starting, so is there a way to enable a button to be used after being clicked?

Comment: Confirmation of the question. Is it the start button you want to control? Are you envisioning, for example, making it ready to click at the start of the test? If so, I don't know of many examples. [Tight Layout with Button States](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#tight-layout-with-button-states)On this page you can see how to control the individual buttons.

Comment: @r-beginners No, it is all the other buttons. After I implemented that start button, once it is pressed and the timer begins, all of the other buttons no longer function.

Comment: In my environment, when the window is open, the Start button, Submit, Next Question, and Skip are ready to be pressed, and when you press the Start button among them, the buttons for Options 1 through 4, which were grayed out, become active and ready to be pressed. I think this is the correct behavior.

Comment: @r-beginners that's correct. I have just realized i have missed some code. From the updated code, after clicking start, the buttons 1 through 4 can be pressed, but dont work as in the pop up coded doesnt pop up

Comment: The default behavior for controlling pop-ups and buttons is either 'True' or 'False', which rewrites the bool value when an event occurs. The current popup is correct because it will be displayed when the time reaches 0.

Comment: So how can I make it so that the other buttons can be pressed whilst the timer is counting down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be dealt with in the main While loop. I couldn't do a good countdown with the timer, so I used a normal counter variable. You can use it to control the number of questions.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import time

q1 = [
        [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(20,1), key="t")],
        [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?"), sg.Button("Start")],
        [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1",button_color=("#ffffff","#151515"), disabled=True, enable_events=True), sg.Button("Option 2", key="2",button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3",button_color=("#00ffff","#151515"), disabled=True), sg.Button("Option 4", key="4",button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip"),sg.Quit()]
    ]

window = sg.Window("Question 1",q1)

seconds = 6
time_cnt = False

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (None,'Quit'):
        break
    elif event == "Start":
        time_cnt = True
        start = time()

    timeleft = seconds
    window.FindElement("t").Update(timeleft)        
    window.refresh()

    if time_cnt:
        seconds -= 1
        if timeleft <= 0:
            sg.popup("no time left")
            window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=True)
            window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=True)
            window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=True)
            window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=True)
            window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=True)
            window.Refresh()                
        else:   
            window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=False)
            window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=False)
            window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=False)
            window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=False)
            window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=False)
            window.Refresh()


    if event == "1":
        sg.popup("Test 1")
    elif event == "2":
        sg.popup("Test 2")
    elif event == "3":
        sg.popup("Test 3")
    elif event == "4":
        sg.popup("Test 4")

window.close()
```

Comment: So is there a way to allow the buttons to be pressed whilst the timer is going down. For example, i click start, then instantly click option 1. Is there a way for "Test 1" to appear before the timer ends instead of after. The idea is so that if the timer runs out, then it goes to the next question, but if they answer before the timer, they get a point if it is right

Comment: The above code shows that if you click on 'option1' immediately after clicking on the start button, you will see a pop-up of 'Test 1'. Also, since it has been changed to a counter, it is possible to select the option button up to six times.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. If your answer is acceptable, please accept it.

Comment: Im unsure what has happened, but the timer has broken as in it doesnt countdown, but decreases when a button is pressed